# iOS 7 — Storyboard default tint color

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios7, tintcolor

I have multiple storyboards in my app and for one specific storyboard I wish to have a different color scheme. This may not be according to iOS 7 guidelines but nonetheless, I am wondering if there is a way to change the tint color for every UIControl for a particular storyboard.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, if you go to the File inspector, you can set the global color per storyboard. In fact, I don't think you can set the tint color for multiple storyboards at once (aside from doing it in code).

Select the File inspector:

[image]

The second section looks like this:

[image]

Change the Global Tint, and that color will be the tint color for your entire storyboard.

Comment: What's document inspector? I have never seen that. Plus, a bit more detail would be helpful given I have already checked most of the options available.

Comment: @flippex17: It's actually called the File inspector. I've edited my answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

**From Code Swift 3**

you can change tint for all view using one line of code

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
```